# Multiple Definitions first defined here

Tags: c, function

For some strange reason every time I compile my project I get this strange error of multiple definitions even though this is the only place I define my function. I use code blocks as my IDE and GCC as the compiler. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <test.h>

int checkForSquare(int num){
    int squared[10001];
    squared[num] = num * num;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++){
        if(squared[i] == num){
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}

int main(){
    for(int x = 0;x <=10000;x++){
        if(checkForSquare(x))
            printf( "%d" , x );
        else
            printf("Not Square");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the `warning` message.

Comment: Remove `test.h` and it should work fine provided that you put a `}` in the end of the code!

Comment: "Multiple definitions" sounds like a linker error, not a compiler error.  What do your compilation and linking commands look like?  Unrelated to your problem, but there's at least one big problem with your `checkForSquare()` function.  You can't assume that the contents of `squared[]` will persist from one call to the next. You could declare it as a global, or declare it in `main()` and pass it as an argument, or you could declare it as `static`, but in any case, it would be good practice to explicitly initialize it first.

Comment: Also,you don't need to loop 10000 times in the function,replace 10000 by num

Comment: This is not the most efficient square-checker I've ever seen

Answer (score -1):

First, you can check the discussion below:
[How to prevent multiple definitions in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672734/how-to-prevent-multiple-definitions-in-c)

Second, please properly align your code at least before you post your question.

Third, I think your checkForSquare() should look like this:

```
int checkForSquare(int num){
    static long squared[10001];
    squared[num] = num * num;
    for(int i = 1; i < num; ++i){
        if(squared[i] == num){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't repost the code formatted, just edit the question.

Comment: @WernerHenze he doesn't have enough rep for that